# How to store BMP image (which is in base64 string format) into oracle 11g database using spring's jdbctemplate class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oracle11g, blob, jdbctemplate

I want to store base64 string (BMP image) into oracle 11g database.
few links i have gone through-

http://forums.asp.net/t/1061466.aspx?how+to+save+image+in+oracle+blob+field+

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_storing_insert_photo_pictures_tables.htm

But I am not getting it how to do this? I have written a code with using this link -

http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/insert-image-using-spring-jdbctemplate

**My Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE  profile_image (img_title VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, img_data blob,);
```

**My code with db Query:**

```
File file = new File("Picture.bmp");
  if (file.exists())
  {
     file.delete();
  }
  OutputStream stream;
  try (stream = new FileOutputStream(file))
  {
     stream.write(data);//data is byte array converted from base64 string 
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
final String UPDATE_USER_PROFILE_PICTURE = "UPDATE profile_image SET img_data = ? WHERE img_title = ?";

final Object[] replacementObjectList = new Object[]
     { new SqlLobValue(stream, (int) file.length(), lobHandler), image_title };

final int count = jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_USER_PROFILE_PICTURE, replacementObjectList, new int[]
     { Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR });
if(count>0)
{return success;}
else
{return failure;}
```

But this query is not updating blob image data and returning failure. Any help?